Recovering a group using tannaka reconstruction
Tannaka reconstruction theorem states that if the category of finite dimensional representations of a group $G$ over $\mathbb{C}$ is given, which is the functor category from the delooping groupoid $\mathcal{B}G$ to $\mathcal{Vect_\mathbb{C}}$, then one can reconstruct the group itself up to isomorphim.
I know that groups $D_8$ and $Q_8$ have the same character table over $\mathbb{C}$, in other words their finite dimensional representations are the same. Now, if we only consider the set(or class?) of representations of $D_8$, then we cannot recover $D_8$ from this information because there is more than one group satisfying these representations, for example $Q_8$. Thus there is no reconstruction here. But when we consider the category of those representations, we are able to reconstruct the group $D_8$ due to Tannaka reconstruction theorem. What is the difference between the set(or class) of representations and the category of representations here? Are morphisms and the compositional structure giving more information about the group?

I explain this here. In short:

If you are given only the category $\text{Rep}(G)$ as a bare category, all you can recover is the number of irreducible representations of $G$, or equivalently the number of conjugacy classes of $G$.
If you are also given the forgetful / fiber functor $F : \text{Rep}(G) \to \text{Vect}$ from representations to vector spaces, you can also recover the dimensions $d_i$ of the irreducible representations of $G$.
If you are also given how the tensor product acts on objects, you can also recover the character table of $G$.
The difference between two finite groups with the same character table is encoded in something fairly subtle: namely, the isomorphisms $F(V \otimes W) \cong F(V) \otimes F(W)$ making $F$ a monoidal functor. In category land, being a monoidal functor is a structure, not a property, and this structure is crucial here.


This is really helpful, thanks a lot. At first I ignored these additional structures on Rep(G), so the theorem made me feel like it was unreal. But now everything is more sensible.
